# Information about _JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: java

Can anyone explain what does Java do when `_JAVA_OPTIONS` Environment variable defined & when application launched on the windows machine?

Comment: See also [Difference between _JAVA_OPTIONS JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and JAVA_OPTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts)

Comment: I don't know but I found _JAVA_OPTIONS in my registry under HKCU/Environment. I delete that environment key and it really helped (Gradle was choking since I had an option in there pointing to a folder that I no longer had access to)

Answer (score 60):

You can use `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to pass *options to any* JVM process started on your system.

For example,

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

When a JVM starts, it parses the value of `_JAVA_OPTIONS` as if the parameters were at the command line of java. You can see the passed parameters via JVisualVM.

For more information, read the blog post: 
[What I discovered while trying to pass Default JVM Parameters](http://progexc.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/what-i-discovered-while-trying-to-pass.html)

Comment: It is generally considered good practice to copy the relevant section into the answer, as blogs and other external references end up getting deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, 
Will do in the future, but the answer was just too long to write in the comment.

Comment: It is better to use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS instead of _JAVA_OPTIONS as per https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4971166

Answer (score 29):

And according to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4971166 undocumented Hotspot-specific `_JAVA_OPTIONS` was superseded by [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) that is included in standard JVMTI specification, does better handling of quoted spaces and should be always preferred.

---

Since JDK 9+ there's also JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS as the preferred replacement, see [What is the difference between JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS when using Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52986487/537554)