# Set Logging Level in Spring Boot via Environment Variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Should it be possible to set logging levels through environment variables alone in a Spring Boot application?

I don't want to use `application.properties` as I'm running on Cloud Foundry and want to pick up changes without a deploy (but after the app has restarted, or restaged to be more precise).

I've tried setting env vars like `LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=TRACE` but that has no effect. Putting `logging.level.org.springframework: TRACE` in `application.properties` does work though.

Comment: The two methods presented in the question should be equivalent based on [_Relaxed Binding_](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).  Maybe there was a bug in Spring Boot at the time (version not specified).

Comment: Maybe the OP changed the example value to simplify the problem description and thereby falsified the problem unintentionally. Please be aware that setting log levels via env variables only works for packages but not for classes! See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This is just an idea, but did you try setting this?

`_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=TRACE`

Theoretically, this way `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=TRACE` will be passed as default JVM argument and should affect every JVM instance in your environment.

Comment: Can confirm in practice: I checked out the [sample-logback](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-logback) project (using version 1.3.0.RELEASE) and ran `mvn spring-boot:run -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=TRACE` which produced a lot of log output. Using the all caps `-DLOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=TRACE` or variants thereof did nothing though.

Comment: If `-D...` parameter works, then setting `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable should actually work! `mvn` command picks them up just like any `java` does. Note the underscore in the beginning though, it is necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781405/ for some more info.

Comment: I'll give that a try - this will be running via the Cloud Foundry Java Buildpack, but hopefully it will respect and pass on the values in `_JAVA_OPTIONS`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java Buildpack, but they have a doc on how to use another environment variable, `JAVA_OPTS`: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-java_opts.md

Comment: I would suggest JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS over _JAVA_OPTIONS as described here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4971166

Answer (score 75):

**Setting log levels via environment variables can only be done for Packages but not for Classes**

I had the same problem as the OP. And I was wondering why some of the users here reported that the proposed solutions worked well while others responded they didn't.
I'm on **Spring Boot 2.1** and the problem obviously changed a bit over the last years, but the current situation is as follows:

### TL;DR

Setting the log level for a **package works**:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_COM_ACME_PACKAGE=DEBUG
```

While setting the log level for a specific **class has no effect**:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_COM_ACME_PACKAGE_CLASS=DEBUG
```

### How can that be?

Have a look at Spring Boot's [LoggingApplicationListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/abe3d3852761430c9f5f1368d82509d0c19ac4d9/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.java#L340-L346).
If you'd debug it and set a breakpoint in the highlighted code block, you'd see that the log level definition for a class `com.acme.mypackage.MyClass` becomes
`com.acme.mypackage.myclass`.
So **a log level definition for a class looks exactly like a log level definition for a package.**

This is related to Spring's [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding), which proposes an upper case notation for environment variables. Thus the typical camel case notation of a class is not visible for the LoggingApplicationListener: The environment variable for `MyClass` has to be defined as `MYCLASS` and will be available as `myclass` in Spring's Environment *(this example ignores the fully-qualified name of the class)*.

Once the camel case notation of the class is lost, during runtime there's no chance to recover the original class name.
Thus log definitions in environment variables don't work for classes but only for packages.

### Is there an alternative?

Yes, you can set the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` environment variable. Its value describes the desired property in JSON style:

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"logging":{"level":{"com":{"acme":{"package":{"Class":"DEBUG"}}}}}}
```

Read more in [Spring's docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-json) (search for "*SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON*" there).

Comment: This was killing me on Spring Boot 2.1.2, nothing in the documentation mentions this limitation. Currently our hack is to redeploy special .jars with debug logging enabled in `application.properties` if we want to debug individual classes. Thanks for the detailed analysis

Comment: This is also acknowledged now in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels saying "The above approach will only work for package level logging. Since relaxed binding always converts environment variables to lowercase, it’s not possible to configure logging for an individual class in this way. If you need to configure logging for a class, you can use the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON variable."

Comment: Thanks, this also applies to Quarkus.... strange.

Answer (score 28):

I also tried to set logging level via environment variable but as already mentioned it is not possible by using environment variable with upper case name, eg. `LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=DEBUG`. I also didn't want to do it via `application.properties` or `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

After digging into class `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener` I've checked that spring boot tries to set logging level `DEBUG` to `ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK` package which is not real package name. So conclusion is that you can use environment variable to set logging level but it needs to be in the form:

`LOGGING_LEVEL_org.springframework=DEBUG`

or

`logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`

Tested on spring boot 1.5.3

Comment: I tried this with Spring Boot 1.3.8 on AWS, but it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: This worked for me with SpringBoot 2.5.3

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can control logging level using environment variable. Here is how I have implemented for my Spring Boot application, deployed on Cloud Foundry platform.

In you log configuration file provide placeholder for logging level to read value from environment variable. Default is INFO.

```
    <logger name="com.mycompany.apps.cf" level="${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
```

And then, in CF deployment manifest file provide environment variable.

```
    applications:
    - name: my-app-name
      memory: 2048
      env:
        APP_LOGGING_LEVEL: DEBUG
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: If you are running the app locally, use -DAPP_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG

Comment: I did do something similar as a workaround, but it means having to know which loggers you want to be able to control at design time, which is rather limiting.

Comment: This is just logback config, nothing specific to Spring / CF

Answer (score 7):

Starting with Spring Boot 2.0.x this works again. Tested with Spring Boot v2.0.9.RELEASE. E.g. enable connection pool debug log:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_COM_ZAXXER=DEBUG java -jar myApp.jar
```

or Spring framework debug log:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=DEBUG java -jar myApp.jar
```

or both:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=DEBUG LOGGING_LEVEL_COM_ZAXXER=DEBUG java -jar myApp.jar
```

See ["Application Poperties" in Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties) for more application properties.

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties

Answer (score 5):

I would anyway suggest you to use Spring profiles:

1. Create 2 properties files:

   `application-local.properties` and
   `application-remote.properties`

   (profile names can be different obviously)
2. Set the logging level in each file accordingly (`logging.level.org.springframework`)
3. Run your application with `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` locally and `-Dspring.profiles.active=remote` for CF.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly this requires knowing the things I want to increase the verbosity of at design time, rather than run time.

Answer (score 5):

Also using Spring Boot (v1.2.3) in Cloud Foundry, I've found that it is possible to adjust the root logging level using an environment variable as follows:

```
$ cf set-env <app name> LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT DEBUG
```

Unfortunately, it does not appear to be possible to dial-down the logging level for specific packages (at least with the version of Java Buildpack and Spring Boot I am using). For example adding the following in addition to the above does not reduce the log level for Spring framework:

```
$ cf set-env <app name> LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK INFO
```

If you are using something like Splunk to gather your logs, you may be able to filter out the noise, however.

Another alternative which looks promising could be based on customisation of the build pack's arguments option (see [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#configuration-and-extension)):

```
$ cf set-env <app name> '{arguments: "-logging.level.root=DEBUG -logging.level.org.springframework=INFO"}'
```

Sadly, I couldn't get this to actually work. I certainly agree that being able to reconfigure logging levels at package level without changing the application code would be handy to get working.

Answer (score 1):

In spring-boot 2.0.0, adding `--trace` works.
For instance `java -jar myapp.jar --debug` or `java -jar myapp.jar --trace`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output

Answer (score 1):

Setting the log level via environment variables for a **package** will work, while setting the log level for a single **class** won't work. This is mentioned in the reference doc for [Spring Boot 2/Log levels](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.7/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels) and [Spring Boot 2/Log levels](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels) .

The log level can be set by using the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` environment variable, eg.

`SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL":"DEBUG","logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder":"TRACE"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html) with [Janino](http://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#janino) to conditionally include different logging configs via [properties or environmental variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)... The base config, logback.xml is using conditionals for development console logging or production file logging... just drop the following files in `/resources/`

---

> logback.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <if condition='property("spring.profiles.active").contains("dev")'>
        <then>
            <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
            <include resource="dev.xml" optional="true"/>
        </then>
    </if>
    <if condition='property("spring.profiles.active").contains("pro")'>
        <then>
            <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
            <include resource="pro.xml" optional="true"/>
        </then>
    </if>
</configuration>
```

---

> dev.xml

```
<included>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%-30([%p] [%c:%L]) » %m%n%rEx</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- CHATTY LOGGERS HERE.-->
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG"/>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <root level="${logback.loglevel}">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</included>
```

---

> pro.xml

```
<included>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex"
                    converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wex"/>
    <property name="FILE_NAME_PATTERN" value="./logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-exec.log"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>FILE_NAME_PATTERN</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>

    <!-- APP SPECIFIC LOGGERS HERE.-->
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</included>
```