# Set Quarkus Logging Category Level via Environment Variables

Tags: environment-variables, quarkus

In Spring, it is possible to set the [Logging Category Level](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-categories) via [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57623996/3250397). I've tried the same in a Quarkus application with the following logger declaration:

```
package org.my.group.resteasyjackson;

public class JacksonResource {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JacksonResource.class);
  
  @GET
  public Set<Quark> list() {
    LOGGER.info("Hello");
    return quarks;
  }
}
```

Executing the build artifact with

`QUARKUS_LOG_CATEGORY_ORG_MY_LEVEL=WARN java -jar my-artifactId-my-version-runner.jar`

will log anything at info level (since it is the default), therefore the "Hello" message.

However, inserting

```
quarkus.log.category."org.my".level=WARN
```

in the `application.properties` file works as desired. Are environment variables in this use case not usable for Quarkus applications?

Comment: did you manage to make it working? I have the same problem. I also try to use that like "QUARKUS_LOG_CATEGORY__ORG_MY__LEVEL"  with additional underscore for quote sign, but it does not help either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just tried with quarkus 1.13.1 and adding extra underscores for the quotes seems to work, try:

QUARKUS_LOG_CATEGORY__ORG_MY__LEVEL=WARN

Comment: And remember it only applies to package, cannot reach class level, same as Spring Boot. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181094/set-logging-level-in-spring-boot-via-environment-variable/57623996#comment135274919_57623996). For Quarkus 2.16 and Openshift 3 I confirm it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
quarkus.log.category."org.my".level=${LOG_LVL:INFO}
```

This simply means: use the log-level from my env variable "LOG_LVL" and if this is not present use INFO as default.

You can set this variable either as an env.variable or pass it through as system parameter during startup, but I'm not sure about the syntax as system parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a system property (!= environment variable) like this:

```
java -Dquarkus.log.category.\"org.my\".level=WARN ...
```

Note: system properties will overrwite their application.properties, except for a [quarkus.profile due to a bug](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13341).

No idea if environment variables can overwrite them too. Maybe the `"` need to be escaped. (I find environment variables brittle, I prefer system properties.)

Comment: Precedence rules for Quarkus https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference