# Can't remove MaxPermSize argument from pivotal tc server Eclipse run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, pivotal-tc

I am running Spring Tool Suite 4 and have been using pivotal tc server for my local development server.  The pivotal tc server has been displaying a warning for a while that MaxPermSize is deprecated, which hasn't been a big issue since it is only a warning.

However, I am not attempting to upgrade from Java 11 to Java 17, and now the server will not start up because of the error `Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'`.  Unfortunately, if I attempt to edit the server run configuration and remove the `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` VM argument, it is automatically added back in.  I assume it is the **Pivotal tc Server Integration for Eclipse** that is adding the argument back in.

Does anyone know how to get it to not add the argument back in, since it is preventing the server from starting?

- STS version: **4.13.0.RELEASE**
- Pivotal tc Server Integration for
  Eclipse version: **4.1.1.202008171738-RELEASE**
- pivotal tc server version: **4.0.2.RELEASE**

Comment: A workaround could be to clone the run configuration, remove the option and manually start it

Comment: @LMC, how do I 'manually' start it?  If I edit the configuration (original or clone), and apply then click 'run', it immediately adds it back into the configuration as it starts up.

Comment: Double check the option is not added by another mechanism: settings.gradle, [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, _JAVA_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736904/2834978) env var

Comment: @LMC unfortunately, no.  In fact, I have found the code in the eclipse-integration-tcserver code base that checks for the param and if not found, adds it back in.  I have added an issue on that project.  Still hoping someone might know of some sort of workaround.

Comment: As a workaround, try adding `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=<value>`