Why is JRE not picking up _JAVA_OPTIONS
I have a strange issue, and googling is finding me everything that is the opposite of this.
I have a need to pass some parameters globally to all JRE instances. To do this, I tested using _JAVA_OPTIONS as a SYSTEM environment variable on Windows. I then ran java -version and saw that Java indicated it picked up the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable. Excellent. Done. I cleaned up my test case and went on with my day.
I passed this info on to another team, who could not reproduce the results. It's now been several days and I'm trying to reproduce the results above. Unfortunately, I don't remember what VM or little details about how exactly I tested the other day. Perhaps I installed an older version of 8 previously? I do remember that java was running from a different path. I've tested on Windows 10 and Windows 11 and for some reason, java will not indicate that it sees _JAVA_OPTIONS. What am I missing?
>echo %_JAVA_OPTIONS%
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT

>where java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\java.exe

>java -version
java version "1.8.0_421"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_421-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.421-b09, mixed mode)

A couple of updates..

I tried JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS as well, and it didn't work.
I also tried running java directly from the C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_421\bin\java.exe path. No fix.
It's unlikely I was running a different version on my previous test. This is really throwing me for a loop as it just worked as intended previously.
I ran Process Monitor and even confirmed in the "Process Start" operation for java.exe that the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable was present.


_JAVA_OPTIONS is an undocumented feature that has apparently been superceded by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736904/139985.  My guess is that the other team is using a newer version of Java than you were using originally.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620.

openjdk 8 seems to have the print so maybe you were trying that version before?

Just tried on my Windows PC, _JAVA_OPTIONS works in JDK23 and JDK8

@StephenC I don't think that's the case: with both variables defined, even Java 21 picks up both options at the same time.

Yea ... superceded is possibly too strong.  But either way, you probably shouldn't use it, since it is undocumented, and there are some "interesting" issues related to using it.  For example on some versions of Java it will give you security warnings.

You're using java from Program Files (x86)? Isn't that just for 32-bit versions?

I suggest you don't use the java8path launcher, that is some kind of wrapper - use the full path to JDK release structure (/xxx/bin/java.exe) directly.

@StephenC I tried JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS which was also ignored.

@DuncG I agree. But running Java directly from the java bin folder (I specified the absolute path to it), still doesn't resolve the issue.

@Appleoddity Perhaps _JAVA_OPTIONS isn't supported in the packaged Oracle JDK8 installation. In the test I mentioned above which worked, I was using OpenJDK8.

@DuncG perhaps the problem is JDK vs JRE? I do not have JDK installed, just JRE. And there is a possibility I tested the environment variable in a non-Oracle JDK environment.

I've got the Oracle JDK 22 and that picks it up.

Are you really sure there is an issue? I have installed Oracle JRE 421. A quick test:
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dtest1=Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dtest2=Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS"

Then run with a few Java versions - all of them pick up the two variables above. The only difference is that no warnings are printed by the Oracle JRE8 update421, all others tested are OpenJDK and they warn about the use of JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and _JAVA_OPTIONS:
C:\>"\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_421\bin\java.exe" -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr test
    test1 = Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    test2 = Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS

C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\java.exe" -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr test
    test1 = Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    test2 = Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS

C:\>\java\jdk-11.0.0.1\bin\java.exe -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dtest1=Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Dtest2=Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS"
    test1 = Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    test2 = Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS

C:\>\java\jdk-14\bin\java.exe -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dtest1=Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Dtest2=Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS"
    test1 = Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    test2 = Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS

C:\>\java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dtest1=Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Dtest2=Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS"
    test1 = Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    test2 = Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS

C:\>\java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dtest1=Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Dtest2=Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS"
    test1 = Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    test2 = Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS

C:\>\java\jdk-23\bin\java.exe -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dtest1=Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Dtest2=Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS"
    test1 = Set by JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    test2 = Set by _JAVA_OPTIONS


Nope. I am not sure. You correctly pointed out, indirectly, that running java -version does not always show the picked up output (specifically for java 8). The JDK does seem to do that. Specifically, OpenJDK 11, no problem. So, the key is to use the -XshowSettings:all option to see them. Thank you. I was able to confirm the environment variable is, in fact, working. When I performed my original tests, I think I tested on a machine with OpenJDK installed.
